# Laravel php artisan calls ALL custom commands

Tags: laravel, command

I am still using Laravel 5.3. (I am upgrading soon, but am stuck with this version until then). I have created several commands and registered them in my kernal.php file.  Here is an example:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        // one off commands
        Commands\Sproj\Command1::class,
        Commands\Sproj\Command2::class,
        Commands\Sproj\Command3::class,
        Commands\Sproj\Command4::class,

        // scheduled commands
        Commands\ScheduledCommand1::class,
        Commands\ScheduledCommand2::class,
        Commands\ScheduledCommand3::class,
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('ScheduledCommand1')->dailyAt('14:00');
        $schedule->command('ScheduledCommand2')->dailyAt('15:00');
        $schedule->command('ScheduledCommand3')->dailyAt('16:00');
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

An example of one of the commands is this:

```
class Command1 extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'sproj:command1';
    protected $description = 'Command Example';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        echo 'Do something here';
    }
}
```

I want to execute one of the 'one-off' commands and so I am using something like `php artisan sproj:command1`

This does work, but it is also executing all the other commands that I have created. Even if I run a built in command such as `php artisan cache:clear`, all my custom commands are running

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you use the same signature?

Comment: No, the signatures are all different, although they do all start with sproj:

Comment: I don't think this is going to be reproducible unless you provide real examples of your commands, so you're unlikely to get any help.

Comment: unfortunately, I am not permitted to upload any real code. It is against company policy. Thanks anyway. I will keep plowing away at it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. My problem was that I made the calls in the `__construct()` method, instead of the `handle()` method.